# Angular Bootstrap Modal Counter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular and would like to display a modal bootstrap dialog which I have done.  I cannot work out how to do the following:

I would like the user to Click 'Add Another' which will increase the counter but not close the dialog.  In reality what I would like to do is when the user clicks add another I will call a database and insert into a record then if successful clear the description text box and allow the user enter another description and increase the count

Here is my modal controller, but unsure where to go from here:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, selected) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: selected || items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Here is a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WRy11KHPNsWnnFGaPN3A?p=preview

Any pointers would be a help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to change

1. Change your counter property to be on an object called viewData rather than putting the counter on 'this'.

   ```
       this.viewData = { counter: 1 };
   ```
2. Change your controller alias from 'app' to 'ctrl' to avoid confusion

```html
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
```

3. Add the ng-click directive to your button element that calls changeDisplay()

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.changeDisplay()">Save Add Another</button>
```

4. Modify your changeDisplay() function to this:

   this.viewData.counter++;

Comment: His thanks for your help but I cannot access your plunk..?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save it.  You should be able to make the changes I outlined above and get it working